# Search Redis for keys with a backslash

Tags: redis

In Redis I have keys like **target:frame:xyz12345** and **target:frame:\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x82**

I can do search for **KEYS target:frame:*** and get all the results but if I try **KEYS target:frame:\*** I get no results. I have tried escaping with **KEYS target:frame:\\*** but this also yields (empty list or set).

How can I search Redis for just those keys with the backslash?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are seeing this in redis-cli, you are seeing escaped binary data.

Try this: `KEYS "target:frame:\xe3*"`. This will match all keys that start with `target:frame:` followed by the byte with value 0xE3

Answer (score 0):

Use `KEYS target:frame:\\*`. The backslash is functioning as an escape character. Double backslashes escape the backslash into a literal backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I forgot to mention that I tried that search and it also failed. Weird, I know. Cheers.

Comment: I tested it in redis-cli, and it worked as expected. LeoMurillo may be onto the answer, though; if you have binary characters being displayed as escape codes, you'll have to search for those characters.